# How can I configure node when I run truffle test?

Tags: truffle, nodejs

How can I get `truffle test` to execute `node` with the `--abort-on-uncaught-exception` option?

I'm guessing that I should probably add something in the Truffle's configuration file (`truffle.js`), but [the docs](http://truffleframework.com/docs/advanced/configuration#configuration) don't say anything about this.

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem to be possible to pass nodejs parameters via truffle command (just checked the script). But you could make your own version of the truffle.cmd/truffle script (in node root folder) adding the required nodejs parameter.